# Why does my browser sometimes not recognize my server's header?

Tags: html, c, web-services, http

If my browser tries to do an HTTP GET on a file that isn't on my server, I just write

> HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\r\n\r\n

to the port. In my browser's web console, I can see that sometimes the error is recognized, but sometimes it's not. Instead the text will be displayed in the browser window. Why does this happen?

If I use curl the response always looks the same, so why does it do this in the browser?

Comment: What's your web browser and is there a publicly available URI that someone can test this against? What about showing the code that supposedly writes this to the socket? I'd bet there's an empty line or two being written before your not found header, probably left over from an earlier loop/iteration/something.

Comment: Could it be that you're writing it twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that most web browsers expect the `Content-Length:` header in all responses.  Even if you are not replying anything; which is pretty funny because the only mandatory header is `Host:` only in requests and only for HTTP 1.1.

I tested with Firefox and I had to write down the following to make it work:

```
HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\r\n
Content-Length: 0\r\n\r\n
```

And then the browser should close the connection.  If you use libcurl, it is probably inserting this and other headers too, like `Date:` for instance.